# How can i change Configuration Properties of a VS Solution using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am compiling a solution and want to not include some projects in the build.
I can manually go to the solution properties and unmark the build check box for those projects , but i am automating this , so is there a way in powershell i can set certain projects as not to build ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead building the solution you can build only the projects from the solution you want to build. Building is not really related to `PowerShell`. I suppose you use `.NET Core` that build the solution file. `dotnet build` is able to build a single project. You can chain `dotnet build` commands to builds each individual project you want, and exclude some of them.